# size of array passed to function

Tags: c++, arrays

```
void quickSort(int a[],int s,int e){
    if(s>e){
        return;
    }

    int pivot = parti(a,s,e);
    cout<<"size "<<sizeof(a)<<endl;
```

When i am passing the array as argument to function, an array of size more than 4 is being treated as an array of size 4. why is it so?

Comment: @tkausl: That is not why.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "pass the array to a function". It looks like you can, but you can't.

This:

```
void quickSort(int a[],int s, int e)
```

is actually:

```
void quickSort(int* a,int s, int e)
```

And, on your system, the size of a pointer is apparently four bytes.

This is why we shall not use `sizeof` to determine the size of a native array, because it's easy to accidentally take the size of something else instead.

Comment: Well, you can pass an array to a function, but the syntax is horrific and you have to know the size at compile time anyway. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay

Comment: @N.Shead: No, that's passing a reference-to-an-array to a function.

Answer (score 0):

[Array-to-pointer decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) happens here (passing an array as function argument). It means whatever array you passed to `quickSort`, `sizeof(a)` will always return the size of the pointer to int.